# Multi-project gradle doesn't import properly

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, groovy

I recently transitioned my gradle project into a multi-project gradle project. Here is my structure as of right now:

```
project-a
    -src
        -main
            -groovy
                -com.first
                    -FirstClass.groovy
    -build.gradle
common
    -src
        -main
            -groovy
                -com.common
                    -CommonClass.groovy
    -build.gradle
- settings.gradle
- build.gradle
```

The class in Project A depends on the a class defined in Common (FirstClass depends on a reference to CommonClass).

Root settings.gradle looks like:

```
rootProject.name = 'root'
include ':common', ':project-a'
```

Root build.gradle looks like:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

subprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    version = '1.0'
    apply plugin : 'java'
    apply plugin : 'groovy'
    apply plugin : 'org.springframework.boot'

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8

    dependencies {
        compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.11'
    }
}
```

build.gradle for Project A looks like:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':common')
}
```

build.gradle for Project Common has its own dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    // ...list dependencies
}
```

Now, if I want to use `CommonClass` in `FirstClass`, I get an import error complaining about `CommonClass` in `FirstClass`. Even if I rebuild CommonProject then ProjectA, I get an error and I'm not sure why. I am suspecting its because it is looking for `com.common.CommonClass` within its own `project-a/src/main/groovy/` directory but it can't find it. Rather, that class is defined in `common/src/main/groovy/` directory. How can I properly have `FirstClass` reference the `common/src/main/groovy` directory and not its own `project-a/src/main/groovy` directory? I'm using Intellij if I can do something with that configuration, that'd be great.

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I reproduced it (although I had to remove `apply plugin : 'org.springframework.boot'`, because it produced an error, and I added `wrapper { gradleVersion = '4.8' }` in main `build.gradle`) and it works for me. I imported the project to IntelliJ with "Use auto-import" - did you have that option checked?

Comment: Hm. I do believe I have it enabled.... Can I get an example of how you were able to reproduce it and fix it?

Comment: I also, just to note, am trying to transform my single gradle project into a multi-gradle project...

Comment: I did the following: 1) manually created `settings.gradle` and all the `build.gradle`s in appropriate directories, 2) opened IntelliJ 2018.1, then File -> Open -> main `build.gradle` -> Open as Project, 3) this shows "Import Project from Gradle" where "Use auto-import" is checked by default and where you select Gradle version (I picked "Use gradle 'wrapper' task configuration"), 4) hit OK. First time I did it, I got some errors related to the spring.boot gradle plugin (it couldn't be found), so I removed it.

Comment: Note that when I have such a project imported, I can reimport it (I suggest you try this, but note it removes the current IntelliJ config) like above, only after clicking "OK" I get the following message "The project file exists. Would you like to overwrite it?", and I click "Yes", and then "Delete Existing Project and Import".

Comment: Ah i see. I actually was creating the project from scratch... so what I did was I went  File -> new Module and made new modules thatway. I then dragged some of the files from my existing single gradle project into the src/main/groovy files into each corresponding module, but the new modules don't have main function or anything (only the Common module has a class with a main function). Is that something I need to do or configure? Is there anything from my steps I've done wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174437/discussion-between-tomasz-linkowski-and-user1871869).

Comment: Can you provide a reproduceable github repo?